# Obter a posição do cursor com jquery

Tags: jquery, html, posicionamento

Existe alguma forma de se obter a posição do cursor em relação à tela quando estou digitando em uma textarea?

Ex: eu digito algum caractere, chamo uma função keyup do jquery e pego a posição em que o cursor está parado, em relação á tela?

**Edit: Acho que me expressei mal, eu quero pegar a posição do último caractere que eu digitei, em relação à tela.**

Answer (score 1):

Espero que ajude:

PS: Executa o código e move o mouse na área cinza de execução.

```js
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eef;
  }
  div {
    padding: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Ve o exemplo completo [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/event.pagex/).

Comment: essa função parece boa, mas tentei fazer no evento "keyup" e não funcionou

Comment: Mostra como estas a tentar fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode guardar as informações do mouse e pegar quando chamar o keyUp:

```
var posicaoMouse = { x: -1, y: -1 };
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    posicaoMouse.x = event.pageX;
    posicaoMouse.y = event.pageY;
});
$( "#campo" ).keyup(function() {
    console.log(posicaoMouse);
});
```